# Search with same key in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm new in mongoDB and I want find a specific users in my collection

In this case I want users with these roles

This is my script

```
db.users.aggregate(
        { $match : 
            {
                'role.name': 'Elite',
                'role.name': 'SuperElite',                
             } 
        }
);
```

This query in my mongoDB works, but I can't create an object javascript like:

```
var query_obj = {'role.name': 'Elite','role.name': 'SuperElite'}
```

I try also

```
db.users.aggregate(
        { $match : 
            {
                'role.name': ['Elite','SuperElite']        
             } 
        }
);
```

but doesn't works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
db.users.aggregate(
        { $match : 
            {
                'role.name':  {$in: ['Elite','SuperElite']   }     
             } 
        }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to find the records, this might be even simpler:

```
db.users.find({'role.name':  {$in: ['Elite','SuperElite']   } })
```

I ran this simple test, and it works as expected:

```
use testdb
db.users.insert({"role":{"name":"Elite", "x":2}})
db.users.insert({"role":{"name":"SuperElite", "x":3}})
db.users.insert({"role":{"name":"whatever", "x":4}})
db.users.find()
db.users.find({'role.name':  {$in: ['Elite','SuperElite']   } })
```

You can find more info here:

- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/
- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

I hope this is helpful.